Booting issue after the updating to Ubuntu 24.04 Noble Numbat
I updated my system to Ubuntu 24.04, Noble Numbat. After updating, the system needs to restart. After restarting, the laptop gets stuck in the boot menu and doesn't enter into the GRUB menu for the booting process. I even changed the booting, but it's unable to boot into Ubuntu.

Can you boot recovery mode from grub menu? What brand/model system? What video card/chip? If nVidia, have you installed proprietary nVidia driver?

Does your system have single boot or a dual boot?
